# how do i make this calculator screen layout using nth-child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

Task:-

1. don't wanna use fix width property in whole program.
2. contents can be arranged as per the addition of the extra contents.
3. we can use table rows and columns.
4. nth-child property must be used.
5. i have used input type buttons so that must be look interactive in layout.
   Thanks a lot guys in advance i need this as soon as possible.
   My Code and Image layout is in comment box please refer.

Comment: Image Link :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQdsp.jpg

Comment: post your code. We aren't a free homework service

Comment: here you go my code link which i have tried https://jsfiddle.net/archan/u6va5hg1/

Comment: please someone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your update Code with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whhbe0v4/)
Just add `colspan="4"` to your td containing output textbox.

Comment: thanks a lot mate by way the how do i increase the size of whole calculator equally

Comment: increase width/height of table.